# Update Gvim buffer without asking for confirmation

Tags: vim, buffer, logging

Is there anyway to make Gvim update the edit buffer without asking for confirmation if the source file changes ? I mean update the edit buffer automatically in every fixed time interval ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Autoread will suppress the prompt:

> When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and
>   it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.
>   When the file has been deleted this is not done.

```
:set autoread
```

In conjunction with :checktime to force a reload.

```
:checktime

:help :checktime
:help 'autoread'
```